# Selecting list elements that aren't in a slice

Tags: python, list, slice

Say I have a list

```
Q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

I believe I can extract the first and every ninth value thereafter using the extended slice notation:

```
Q[::9]
```

Which should give:

```
[0,9,18]
```

But how can I similarly select all the elements *apart from* those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean this?

```
>>> lis = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
>>> lis[1::9]
[1, 10]
```

Extended slice notations:

```
lis[start : stop : step]  #default values : start = 0, stop = len(lis), step = 1
```

You can pass your own value for `start`(by default 0 be used)

**Update:**

```
>>> lis = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
>>> se = set(range(0, len(lis),9))   #use a list if the lis is not huge.
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(lis) if i not in se]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

#for your example even this will work:
>>> [x for i,x in enumerate(lis) if i%9 != 0]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

Comment: Whoops, I think my question was ambiguous. I meant in that list, how can I select all the other values except for those returned by Q[::9].

Answer (score 1):

In case you have not repeated numbers, this is a general solution for any collection of numbers (not necessarily consecutive):

```
>>> Q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
>>> list(set(Q).difference(Q[::9]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
>>>
```

It uses `set.difference`s to get the `set` that is the difference between the original list and the sublist to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

From OP's comment: *How can I select all the other values except for those returned by Q[::9] ?*

I use list comprehension:

[image]

```
Q = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
print(Q)
print(Q[::9])                               # [0, 9, 18]
print([x for x in Q if x not in Q[::9]])    # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```